# Has anyone started creating React Native API/plugins/modules?

Tags: module, components, cordova-plugins, react-native

I would like to port any of my apps over to react native from cordova/phonegap but being so new, react native is a bit limited and doesn't have all the functionality I would need.  Anyone know of a camera plugin for react native?

**UPDATE**:

Not sure why this got voted down, I'm not asking for an opinion, I'm asking for a source!  Either way I answered my own question.

**ANSWER**:

[ReactNativeModules.com](http://reactnativemodules.com/) has a community run list of [react native components and modules](http://reactnativemodules.com/).

Answer (score 3):

It's only been out for a day, I think it's pretty clear that while people are going to do this kind of thing, it's a bit early yet. I imagine they'll be distributed with something like Cocoapods perhaps, since they'll be written as [Native Modules](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#content). There's an ongoing discussion about the form this will take [on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/60).

That said, there are some things that aren't needed as plugins. For example, Phonegap has a statusbar plugin, but with React Native you can just set the statusbar transparency in Xcode as you would with a normal app. For things like Vibration, which again I think would be a Phonegap plugin, see the [React Native APIs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/vibrationios.html#content). For things like Geolocation, which would normally be available via the browser, take a look at [polyfills](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#content). There are loads more examples like this so I'd suggest giving the docs a thorough read.

Comment: I know it's early but it also has been available to some developers for months now.  I was just wondering if anyone had started.  Not sure why I'm getting down votes?! :(

Comment: I think because your original question is a bit "woolly", maybe try making it more specific - what plugins are you missing, for example? That's why I tried to give an answer with some specifics in it.